# MS Access: Compare two columns for Matches - Names in Different Order

Tags: ms-access, compare

I'm trying to compare two different columns in Access 2016.  Both contain people's names, but not in the same order in both.

Name
Harris, Keisha
Banaghan, John
Garcia Silveira, Ana

NameFormat2

Keisha Melinda Harris

John C. Banaghan

Ana Lucia Garcia Silveira

Currently, when comparing these two columns, they all flag, as they are not exact matches.

The names in the first column are always shorter than the FULL name that lives in the second column.

Is there a way, be it a query or VBA or any other option, to say that if all of the names in the first column are contained in the second column, then it's a match and to move on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: If the data has not already been collected just add a primary key to the name table and use that to uniquely identify people.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but you could create a VBA function that does the check by splitting the two fields into arrays and looping them. Something like this seems to work:

```
Function fCompareNames(strName1 As String, strName2 As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim astrName1() As String
    Dim astrName2() As String
    Dim intLoop1 As Integer
    Dim intLoop2 As Integer
    Dim intNames As Integer
    Dim intMatch As Integer
    strName1 = Replace(strName1, ",", "")
    strName2 = Replace(strName2, ",", "")
    astrName1 = Split(strName1, " ")
    astrName2 = Split(strName2, " ")
    intNames = UBound(astrName1) - LBound(astrName1) + 1
    For intLoop1 = LBound(astrName1) To UBound(astrName1)
        For intLoop2 = LBound(astrName2) To UBound(astrName2)
            If astrName1(intLoop1) = astrName2(intLoop2) Then
                intMatch = intMatch + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next intLoop2
    Next intLoop1
    If intMatch = intNames Then fCompareNames = True
fExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Function
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "fCompareNames", vbOKCancel + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume fExit
End Function
```

You may need to add some extra `Replace`s to deal with things like "." in the name.

In the examples given, it returns true for the first two (Keisha Harris and John Banaghan) and false for the last (Ana Silveira) as there appears to be a spelling mistake in the second instance of her surname (Silbeira).

Regards,